# How to use relations in Views to get Content type fileds when I use Taxonomy

Tags: views

Good day. I have Content type with Taxonomy field. Right now I try to build Views by this Taxonomy vocabulary. And I want to use (how?) relations to get access to Content type fields. So, idea is to have View by Taxonomy, but use fields of content type, which has this taxonomy as field.

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to what you want to do?
https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/taxonomy/views

Comment: No. I want to get Node fields throught taxonomy term. It means, that I know taxonomy term and know that it is used in node and want to see fields from this node.